# Toast notification on windows phone 8 without sound and vibration

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm going to make a simple toast notification using periodic task of background agent, what 
I'm asking is how can I show notification in specific time, but without playing sound notification or vibration, is there any way to achieve it?

Since what I've seen at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=vs.92%29.aspx that VibrateController is unsupported api in background agent

Thanks!

Comment: Were u able to invoke the periodic task in less than 30 minutes? I mean were able to customize the default time of periodic agent? If so how???

Comment: sorry can't help you much with the 30min interval, cmiiw but from what I've read it's designed that way, you could use ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(string name, TimeSpan delay) method though for debugging purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely up to the user to decide whether he/she want the sounds and vibration or not. There is nothing we can do as a developer to control such things. I believe it is one of Microsofts philosophies to not end up like Android in such matters.

Comment: I'll just add that a live tile is the mechanism you're supposed to use if you want to display a non-intrusive notification.

Comment: I'm sorry but using live tile is not an option, so no other workaroundfor this? like using FLAGS in android? anyway thanks

Comment: Sorry there is no way around this.